# Erro: HTTP Status 500 - org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject

Tags: java, json, java-ee, post, java-8

Em meu sistema java apareceu este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou suando a ferramenta POSTMAN para estudar o caso.

> HTTP Status 500 - org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject

**Código:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class teste1
 */
@WebServlet("/teste1")
public class teste1 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public teste1() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String nome = request.getParameter("nome");

        PrintWriter saida = response.getWriter();
        saida.println("teste1: "+nome);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) formatJson(request.getReader());

        System.out.println(json.toString());

        doGet(request, response);

        formatJson(request.getReader());

        String body =  request.getReader().lines().reduce("",(acc, actual)->acc+actual );
        System.out.println(body);

    }

    private JSObject formatJson(BufferedReader reader){

        StringBuffer bs = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;

        try{
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                bs.append(line);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(bs.toString());
        return (JSObject) json;
    }

}
```

Como devo proceder para encontrar a solução para este erro ?

Comment: A linha `return (JSObject) json;` vai lançar um erro necessariamente. Os tipos são distintos. Tente outra maneira de transformar a string em `JSObject `

Comment: Algum sugestão ???

Comment: Usar uma única biblioteca de JSON

Comment: Olhe seus imports : `import org.json.JSONObject;  import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject;` são duas bibliotecas distintas

Comment: Remove o import `jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject`

No método formatJson você cria um objeto `JSONObject` e converte para `JSObject`.

Depois nessa linha, você reverte o que você fez anteriormente:

`JSONObject json = (JSONObject) formatJson(request.getReader());`

não faz sentido fazer isso, trabalha só com o `JSONObject`